# How to Create a Catch-all Copy Field in Apache Solr?

Tags: search, solr

Using the Solr admin interface under `Schema`, I am trying to create a catch-all Copy Field that searches all other fields.

When entering `*` as the `source` and `search` as the `destination`, the admin interface returns:

> error processing commands

How can a catch-all Copy Field that searches all other fields be created?

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Answer (score 3):

In your `schema.xml` you can have this fields:

```
<field name="destination" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/> 
<field name="country" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" /> 
<field name="city" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" /> 
<field name="state" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
```

`country, city and state` are the source fields.

then can add the source field to destination as the following:

```
<copyField source="city" dest="destination"/> 
<copyField source="state" dest="destination"/> 
<copyField source="country" dest="destination"/>
```

Or you can also have something like as your source fields

```
<field name="destination" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
<field name="country" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"> 
<field name="city" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" /> 
<copyField source="*_y" dest="destination"/>
```

You can apply any suitable field type for your field `destination`

You can also add a field type `text` as below. This is an example for your reference. Which field type to use and what `tokenizer` to use and `filters` to use is all depends on your requirements.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```